# Program type already present: ActivityLifecycleListener$LifecycleEntry

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-storage, android-workmanager

Since upgrading Firebase Storage to version `16.1.0`:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0
```

Gradle fails with  error message:

> Program type already present: com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ActivityLifecycleListener$LifecycleEntry

How to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating [work-testing](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/android.arch.work/work-testing) & [work-runtime](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/android.arch.work/work-runtime) to `1.0.0`, with [firebase-work](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/android.arch.work/work-firebase) `1.0.0-alpha11`

the build at first still failed with:

> Program type already present: com.google.firebase.storage.internal.Sleeper

but after cleaning the project, it then built again.

Answer (score -1):

Update the google play gradle plugin version to latest version, it  might solve your problem.

Comment: how does this attempt to answer the question? this is a dependency problem.